# Python: AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'

Tags: python, tweepy

soy principiante en programación, y recientemente me encuentro con problemas de la autenticación de OAuthHandler, como puedo solucionarlo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @DarkStormSeeker , agrega tu código a la pregunta en lugar de la imagen, también el error, tendrás más existo de esta forma en la búsqueda de respuestas, no olvides leer  [ask], saludos!

Comment: Estas llamando a un modulo situado en el mismo directorio `tweepy.py`. Esto hace que sea este módulo el importado , causando el error. No llames a módulos propios con nombres de bibliotecas de la librería estándar o de paquetes instalados.

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Renombra el archivo que tu creas llamado `tweepy.py` con otro nombre para evitar este conflicto de imports.

Answer (score 0):

El código escrito es así:
(fue el segundo intento con consumer_key)

```
import tweepy

consumer_key =""
consumer_secret= ""
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""


from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
auth= tweepy.OAuthHandler(_consumer_token, _consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(_access_token, _access_token_secret)
api= tweepy.API(auth)
print (api.verify_credentials())

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print (tweet.text)
```